# Nagios - External command error: Command failed

Tags: nagios

I followed a [tutorial](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1030102/~/how-to%3A-configuring-nagios-to-receive-solidfire-snmp-traps-) for setting SNMP trap for Nagios Core 4.4.3.

After Service *snmptrapd* executes the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echocmd="/bin/echo"    
CommandFile="/var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd"    
datetime=`date +%s`    
cmdline="[$datetime] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;$1;$2;$3;$4"

 `$echocmd $cmdline >> $CommandFile`
```

It gives following error (found in /var/log/messages):

> nagios: External command error: Command failed

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is this file exists `/var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd`? Try put there a debug code in your script: `echo "${cmdline}" >> /tmp/debug-output.log`

Comment: [root@nagios-nou bali]# cat /tmp/debug-output.log
[1578418819] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;sonicwall.intranet.adrvest.ro;trap-service;1;This trap indicates an event from internal firewall activity. 647 Interface X4 Link Is Down
[1578418826] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;sonicwall.intranet.adrvest.ro;trap-service;1;This trap indicates an event from internal firewall activity. 646 Interface X4 Link Is Up
[root@nagios-nou bali]#

This is what I get after I put the debugger in my script. Seems like everything is working fine, yet it gives me that error. No idea why

Comment: Okey, try use this command as your Nagios user: `/bin/echo "$(date +%s) PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;sonicwall.intranet.adrvest.ro;trap-service;1;This trap indicates an event from internal firewall activity. 647 Interface X4 Link Is Down" >> /var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd`

Comment: I cannot run the command from nagios user because in /etc/passwd the user is with no login.
 
nagios:x:998:995::/var/spool/nagios:/sbin/nologin
I have tried from root user and:
 
In /var/log/messages:
 
Jan 10 21:03:47 nagios-nou nagios: External command error: Malformed command
 
In /var/log/nagios/nagios.log
 
[1578683079] External command error: Malformed command
 
Do i have a chance to use nagios core with snmptrap?

Comment: Okay, last try. Run this as root user: `/bin/echo "[$(date +%s)] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;sonicwall.intranet.adrvest.ro;trap-service;1;This trap indicates an event from internal firewall activity. 647 Interface X4 Link Is Down" > /var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd`

Comment: Yes, this works. But only if i manually run it in terminal. A thing i changed in this command was the hostname. I switched that with its ip. Do you know how to insert that as code in my script so it can run automatically?

Comment: @Rohlik I managed to fix it. Its all good. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: No problem, it would be useful, if you put here your working piece of code. You know, for others who can have similar issue like you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : solved. Had to comment datetime and modify the next line of code the way Rohlik told me.

```
#!/bin/sh
echocmd="/bin/echo"
CommandFile="/var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd"
####datetime=`date +%s`
cmdline="[$(date +%s)] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;$1;$2;$3;$4"
`$echocmd $cmdline >> $CommandFile`
```